# Floyd Steinberg algorithm implementation in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to implement Floyd-Steinberg algorithm i c# to dithered 24 bit image to 8 bit but i have exception error System.IndexOutOfRangeException (Index was outside the boundaries of the array.) in line :g1[x - 1, y + 1] += err_g * 3 / 16; Has anyomeone tell me where I made a mistake and what should i change?
r1 means old pixel
r2 - new pixel

```
{

            Color Pix;
           int[,] r1 = new int[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
           int[,] r2 = new int[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
           int[,] g1 = new int[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
           int[,] g2 = new int[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
           int[,] b1 = new int[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
           int[,] b2 = new int[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];




            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {


                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    Pix = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    r1[x, y] = (Pix.R + Pix.G + Pix.B);
                    g1[x, y] = (Pix.R + Pix.G + Pix.B);
                    b1[x, y] = (Pix.R + Pix.G + Pix.B);               
                }
            }

            int err_r;
            int err_g;
            int err_b;

            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {


                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {

                    if (g1[x, y] < 128)
                    {
                        g2[x, y] = 0;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g2[x, y] = 255;

                    }
                    if (r1[x, y] < 128)
                    {
                        r2[x, y] = 0;
                                       }
                    else
                    {
                        r2[x, y] = 255;
                                       }
                    if (b1[x, y] < 128)
                    {
                        b2[x, y] = 0;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        b2[x, y] = 255;

                    }

                    err_r = r1[x,y] - r2[x,y];
                    err_g = g1[x,y] - g2[x,y];
                    err_b = b1[x,y] - b2[x,y];



                    if (x < bmp.Width - 1)
                        r1[x + 1, y] += err_r * 7 / 16;
                        g1[x + 1, y] += err_g * 7/ 16;
                        b1[x + 1, y] += err_b * 7/ 16;
                    if (y < bmp.Height - 1)
                        r1[x, y + 1] += err_r * 5 / 16;
                        g1[x, y + 1] += err_g * 5 / 16;
                        b1[x, y + 1] += err_b * 5 / 16;
                    if (x < bmp.Width - 1 && y < bmp.Height - 1)
                        r1[x + 1, y + 1] += err_r / 16;
                        g1[x + 1, y + 1] += err_g / 16;
                        b1[x + 1, y + 1] += err_b / 16;
                    if (x > 0 && y < bmp.Height - 1)
                        r1[x - 1, y + 1] += err_r * 3 / 16;
                        g1[x - 1, y + 1] += err_g * 3 / 16;
                        b1[x - 1, y + 1] += err_b * 3/ 16;



                }
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {


                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r2[x, y], g2[x, y], b1[x, y]));

                }
            }
```

Comment: it is c#, not python, you have to enclose code in `if`s into { and }

Comment: `Pit998` if you fix your formatting as well you maybe able to realize what `pascx64` is talking about.. here is a take away, if you are going to use conditional statements that will require more than 1 check or method or any type of assignment, wrap the code around `{}` it makes it easier to read as well as debug that is if you have debugged it or not.. also when writing code you should always test it by stepping thru / debugging your own code..

Comment: Please attempt to pull out the relevant lines of code, or create a smaller example to demonstrate the issue you are having...

Comment: Please do not remove relevant portions of your code after the issue has been solved. It makes the answer no longer relevant. If your problem has been solved by a user, please mark the answer as the Accepted Answer. If you have solved it yourself, please submit and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you forgot to put "{ }" after your ifs :

```
if (x < bmp.Width - 1)
{
...
}
 if (y < bmp.Height - 1)
{
...
}
...
```